# Extract string in double bracket

Tags: linux, unix

How to extract string in double bracket like below

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>[[title]]</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hi! You are in the [[environment]] environment!
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can ask your question here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Parsing XML should be done with proper XML parsing tools, which bash doesn't offer by default. But as the input is simple, there are valid options.

Using grep:

```
echo $HTML | grep -oPm1 "(?<=<title>)[^<]+"
```

Using python (needs 'lxml' module installed):

```
echo $(echo $HTML | python -c "import sys,lxml.html; tree=lxml.html.fromstring(sys.stdin.read()); r=tree.xpath('//title/text()'); print(r[0])")
```